# How can I relate the outputs of my neural network with a known relation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a neural network which has a Dense(2) layer right at the end. This produces two outputs as expected. I am training this on sequence/timeseries data.

My training labels are structured like this (each row corresponds to the output for each sequence).

```
A | B | C
---------
2 | 0 | 2
1 | 1 | 4
1 | 0 | 5
3 | 1 | 7
```

As you can see, `C[i] = C[i-1] + A - B`,

My network so far predicts A and B but not very well. I want to be able to introduce the fact that C is related to A and B as above. How do I go about doing this? I can change the number of output layers to 3 but this won't use a known relationship which I think can increase the accuracy of my prediction.

I was thinking of using a `merge` layer such as `Add` and `Subtract` (as [defined](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) in the API) but I can't quite figure out how. How do I specify to use the previous outputs?

Thank you!

Comment: If C is a definite function of the A and B's why not just find C after you've output all the A's and B's?

Comment: @enumaris I'm doing that but I want to be able to use C to train A and B, like an additional feature of sorts. Right now my predictions of A and B are wrong so even C is wrong.

Comment: You might want to take a look at a recurrent neural network if you want to be feeding outputs of your neural network back into itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network

Comment: I tried to do that but it performed poorly unfortunately. I'm getting more success with convolutional neural networks.

Comment: I think you want your network to discover a general rule (your mathematical relationship) that generalizes beyond your training sample distribution. It is a hard problem that you won't solve simply by adding some layer.